# Need help webscraping with Beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the stock-tickers of the chart embedded on the right of this page. 
http://investsnips.com/list-of-publicly-traded-micro-cap-diversified-biotechnology-and-pharmaceutical-companies/

When inspecting the html, the stock-symbols seem to be embedded here, under title ("NASDAQ:ADMA"), with below representing the code for one symbol:

```
<td class="symbol-short-name-container" title="NASDAQ:ADMA" style="cursor: 
pointer;"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ%3AADMA" 
target="_blank">ADMA Biologics</a></td>
```

However, I'm failing to capture this code via find_all.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

import re

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://investsnips.com/list-of-publicly-traded-micro-cap-diversified-biotechnology-and-pharmaceutical-companies/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

body = soup.body (#It seems to be under body)
```

After which

```
body.find_all('tr',  class_="ticker quote-ticker-inited")
[]  # empty list

body.find_all('td',  class_="symbol-short-name-container")
[] #empty list
```

Comment: it looks like this table is generated dynamically with JavaScript

Comment: why to scrape from this site?

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I think it's possible to scrape JavaScript generated tables, I will have to look into it.